# How to get an VBA Array object with function like sort, filter or join

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I work with VBA, mostly for Excel.

To optimise calculation time, I use array like Dim myArray()

Is there any array class, object, or library existing for VBA which include functions like :

```
myArray.sort
myArray.sortFromColumn(columnNumber) 'For 2D array...
myArray.join(anotherArray)
myArray.split(index)
myArray.filter(key)
myArray.numFilter(>8)
...
```

I've found many code to realise each operation (specially sort), but nothing to get most in one "package".

Thanks,

Comment: `Join` and `Filter` are built-in functions.  `Split` is also a built-in function, but that "splits" a string into an array.

Comment: Yes, existing function, but not really for this application. `Filter` convert all to String, so `Filter(Array(1, 10, 210), 1)` will return all elements of the array because each number has 1 in it. `Join` will clearly not join 2 arrays but only String.

Comment: Have you considered using a database instead of code?

Comment: Ah, I see.  I just write my own custom functions.  I have a `QuickSort` method and a `ConcatenateArray` method.  I also tend to use `Collections` instead of `Arrays` because they are more dynamic.

Comment: Exactly, I used also own custom function for now, but project grow and I need _a better well-construct package_ to use it. MultiDimensionnal array is coming, multiple numeric criteria filtering... And I hope I haven't to realise a mini library like this on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a job I use now :
https://github.com/Grominet/SixSigmaExcelPack/blob/master/ClassArray

Maybe it will be usefull for someone.
Just Copy/Paste code into a VBA ClassModule.

In your VBA Module, call it by :

```
dim myTab as ClassArray
set myTab = InstantiateClassArray
```

And after you can manage it, like myTab.sort, myTab.Filter...
It's not perfect and maybe not fully debugged, but it's a good base to start.